# How to iterate through all combinations of columns and apply function by group in R?

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table` named `dt`

```
  set.seed(1)
  dt <- data.table(expand.grid(c("a","b"),1:2,1:2,c("M","N","O","P","Q")))
  dt$perf <- rnorm(nrow(dt),0,.01)
  colnames(dt) <- c("ticker","par1","par2","row_names","perf")
```

My goal is to iterate through all combinations of `par1` and `par2` by `row_names` and pick the one that maximizes `cumprod(mean(perf)+1)-1`.
Let's look at the data so this makes more sense visually.

```
dt[order(row_names,ticker,par1,par2)]
    ticker par1 par2 row_names         perf
 1:      a    1    1         M  0.011462284
 2:      a    1    2         M -0.004252677
 3:      a    2    1         M  0.005727396
 4:      a    2    2         M -0.003892372
 5:      b    1    1         M -0.024030962
 6:      b    1    2         M  0.009510128
 7:      b    2    1         M  0.003747244
 8:      b    2    2         M -0.002843307
```

For each `ticker` and `row_names` we have `2 x 2 = 4` combinations of `par1` and `par2`, namely, `(1,1) (1,2) (2,1) (2,2)`.

I would like to calculate the `mean` of `perf` associated with `ticker = a, par1 = 1, par2 = 1` with all the `perf` associated with all other combinations for `ticker = b`. Using numbers from the image above,

```
res
       a_perf       b_perf
1: 0.01146228 -0.024030962
2: 0.01146228  0.009510128
3: 0.01146228  0.003747244
4: 0.01146228 -0.002843307

apply(res,1,mean)
[1] -0.006284339  0.010486206  0.007604764  0.004309488
```

Then, we repeat this process for `ticker = a, par1 = 1, par2 = 2` with all other combinations for `ticker = b`.

We would repeat this process for all combinations of `par1` and `par2` with each `row_names`.

**EDIT::: Using @earch's suggestion we get the following:**

```
tmp <- lapply(split(dt, dt$row_names), calcCombMeans)
$M
   a.row b.row          mean
1      1     2 -0.0022140524
2      3     2 -0.0032599264
3      5     2  0.0025657555
4      7     2  0.0033553619
5      1     4  0.0048441350
6      3     4  0.0037982609
7      5     4  0.0096239429
8      7     4  0.0104135493
9      1     6 -0.0072346110
10     3     6 -0.0082804850
11     5     6 -0.0024548031
12     7     6 -0.0016651967
13     1     8  0.0005593545
14     3     8 -0.0004865195
15     5     8  0.0053391624
16     7     8  0.0061287688
```

From here, I would like to pick the `max(mean)` for `row_names M,N,O,P,Q`. One way to do that would be this if I did not care about referencing indices later on:

```
res <- sapply(1:length(tmp),function(i) which.max(tmp[[i]]$perf))
[1]  8  6  3 12 16
```

This would be how I would calculate my desired end-result with completion:

```
res <- rbindlist(tmp,id="row_names")
  res <- res[,list(best=max(perf),best_idx = which.max(perf)),by=row_names]
   row_names        best best_idx
1:         M 0.010413549        8
2:         N 0.009508122        6
3:         O 0.009314068        3
4:         P 0.008883106       12
5:         Q 0.009316006       16
```

I haven't decided whether I need the `best_idx` information (I probably will in order to replicate the exact calculation of a specific `row_names`), but using this `res`, I can calculate my `cumRet` by doing:

```
res[,cumRet:= cumprod(best+1)-1]
> res
   row_names        best best_idx      cumRet
1:         M 0.010413549        8 0.01041355
2:         N 0.009508122        6 0.02002068
3:         O 0.009314068        3 0.02952123
4:         P 0.008883106       12 0.03866657
5:         Q 0.009316006       16 0.04834280
```

@earch's really helps being able to see the process of calculating all these combinations. I was wondering if there was a more efficient solution through using `data.table`'s functionality. My real data set is much larger than this (millions of rows), and the combinations will start to take a toll.

**EDIT #2::: After being able to step through the process, I have figured out a very fast solution!**

```
tmp <- dt[,list(par1=par1[which.max(perf)],par2=par2[which.max(perf)],perf=max(perf)),by=list(ticker,row_names)]
    res <- tmp[,list(perf=mean(perf),par1= paste(par1,collapse=","),par2=paste(par2,collapse=",")),by=row_names]
```

Using `data.table` allows me to calculate the max perf by group and ticker combinations. Then after doing that, I can group by `row_names`. And it gets the same results!

```
> res
   row_names        perf par1 par2
1:         M 0.010413549  2,2  2,1
2:         N 0.009508122  2,2  1,1
3:         O 0.009314068  1,1  2,1
4:         P 0.008883106  2,1  2,2
5:         Q 0.009316006  2,2  2,2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT #2::: After being able to step through the process, I have figured out a very fast solution!**

```
tmp <- dt[,list(par1=par1[which.max(perf)],par2=par2[which.max(perf)],
                                           perf=max(perf)),
                                           by=list(ticker,row_names)]
res <- tmp[,list(perf=mean(perf),par1= paste(par1,collapse=","),
                                          par2=paste(par2,collapse=",")),by=row_names]
```

Using `data.table` allows me to calculate the max perf by group and ticker combinations. Then after doing that, I can group by `row_names`. And it gets the same results!

```
> res
   row_names        perf par1 par2
1:         M 0.010413549  2,2  2,1
2:         N 0.009508122  2,2  1,1
3:         O 0.009314068  1,1  2,1
4:         P 0.008883106  2,1  2,2
5:         Q 0.009316006  2,2  2,2
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what values the cumulative product is being taken over, but here's a function that calculates the mean between all perf combinations of a and b within a row_names. It should give you what you need to finish the task:

```
calcCombMeans <- function(dt) {
  a.rows <- which(dt$ticker == "a")
  b.rows <- which(dt$ticker == "b")
  rep.rows <- expand.grid(a.row = a.rows, b.row = b.rows)
  rep.rows$mean <- sapply(1:nrow(rep.rows), function(i) {
    mean(dt$perf[unlist(rep.rows[i, ])])
  })
  dt$means <- lapply(1:nrow(dt), function(i) {
    if(dt$ticker[i] == "a") {
      filter(rep.rows, a.row == i)$mean
    } else {
      filter(rep.rows, b.row == i)$mean
    }
  })
  dt
}

do.call(rbind, lapply(split(dt, dt$row_names), calcCombMeans))

    ticker par1 par2 row_names          perf
 1:      a    1    1         M -0.0062645381
 2:      b    1    1         M  0.0018364332
 3:      a    2    1         M -0.0083562861
 4:      b    2    1         M  0.0159528080
 5:      a    1    2         M  0.0032950777
 6:      b    1    2         M -0.0082046838
 7:      a    2    2         M  0.0048742905
 8:      b    2    2         M  0.0073832471
 9:      a    1    1         N  0.0057578135
10:      b    1    1         N -0.0030538839
11:      a    2    1         N  0.0151178117
12:      b    2    1         N  0.0038984324
13:      a    1    2         N -0.0062124058
14:      b    1    2         N -0.0221469989
15:      a    2    2         N  0.0112493092
16:      b    2    2         N -0.0004493361
17:      a    1    1         O -0.0001619026
18:      b    1    1         O  0.0094383621
19:      a    2    1         O  0.0082122120
20:      b    2    1         O  0.0059390132
21:      a    1    2         O  0.0091897737
22:      b    1    2         O  0.0078213630
23:      a    2    2         O  0.0007456498
24:      b    2    2         O -0.0198935170
25:      a    1    1         P  0.0061982575
26:      b    1    1         P -0.0005612874
27:      a    2    1         P -0.0015579551
28:      b    2    1         P -0.0147075238
29:      a    1    2         P -0.0047815006
30:      b    1    2         P  0.0041794156
31:      a    2    2         P  0.0135867955
32:      b    2    2         P -0.0010278773
33:      a    1    1         Q  0.0038767161
34:      b    1    1         Q -0.0005380504
35:      a    2    1         Q -0.0137705956
36:      b    2    1         Q -0.0041499456
37:      a    1    2         Q -0.0039428995
38:      b    1    2         Q -0.0005931340
39:      a    2    2         Q  0.0110002537
40:      b    2    2         Q  0.0076317575
    ticker par1 par2 row_names          perf
                                                      means
 1: -0.0022140524, 0.0048441350,-0.0072346110, 0.0005593545
 2:     -0.002214052,-0.003259926, 0.002565755, 0.003355362
 3: -0.0032599264, 0.0037982609,-0.0082804850,-0.0004865195
 4:         0.004844135,0.003798261,0.009623943,0.010413549
 5:      0.002565755, 0.009623943,-0.002454803, 0.005339162
 6:     -0.007234611,-0.008280485,-0.002454803,-0.001665197
 7:      0.003355362, 0.010413549,-0.001665197, 0.006128769
 8:  0.0005593545,-0.0004865195, 0.0053391624, 0.0061287688
 9:      0.001351965, 0.004828123,-0.008194593, 0.002654239
10:      0.001351965, 0.006031964,-0.004633145, 0.004097713
11:      0.006031964, 0.009508122,-0.003514594, 0.007334238
12:      0.004828123, 0.009508122,-0.001156987, 0.007573871
13:     -0.004633145,-0.001156987,-0.014179702,-0.003330871
14:     -0.008194593,-0.003514594,-0.014179702,-0.005448845
15:      0.004097713, 0.007573871,-0.005448845, 0.005399987
16:      0.002654239, 0.007334238,-0.003330871, 0.005399987
17:      0.004638230, 0.002888555, 0.003829730,-0.010027710
18:         0.004638230,0.008825287,0.009314068,0.005092006
19:      0.008825287, 0.007075613, 0.008016787,-0.005840653
20:         0.002888555,0.007075613,0.007564393,0.003342332
21:      0.009314068, 0.007564393, 0.008505568,-0.005351872
22:         0.003829730,0.008016787,0.008505568,0.004283506
23:      0.005092006, 0.003342332, 0.004283506,-0.009573934
24:     -0.010027710,-0.005840653,-0.005351872,-0.009573934
25:      0.002818485,-0.004254633, 0.005188837, 0.002585190
26:      0.002818485,-0.001059621,-0.002671394, 0.006512754
27:     -0.001059621,-0.008132739, 0.001310730,-0.001292916
28: -0.0042546332,-0.0081327395,-0.0097445122,-0.0005603642
29: -0.0026713940,-0.0097445122,-0.0003010425,-0.0029046889
30:  0.0051888365, 0.0013107303,-0.0003010425, 0.0088831056
31:  0.0065127541,-0.0005603642, 0.0088831056, 0.0062794591
32:      0.002585190,-0.001292916,-0.002904689, 0.006279459
33:  0.0016693329,-0.0001366148, 0.0016417911, 0.0057542368
34:      0.001669333,-0.007154323,-0.002240475, 0.005231102
35:     -0.007154323,-0.008960271,-0.007181865,-0.003069419
36: -0.0001366148,-0.0089602706,-0.0040464226, 0.0034251540
37:     -0.002240475,-0.004046423,-0.002268017, 0.001844429
38:      0.001641791,-0.007181865,-0.002268017, 0.005203560
39:         0.005231102,0.003425154,0.005203560,0.009316006
40:      0.005754237,-0.003069419, 0.001844429, 0.009316006
                                                      means
```

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly the process I want to implement. I have to work on making adjustments so it works when the number of unique `tickers` is unique, and making it run as efficiently as possible, but thank you for giving me an excellent start!

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to do this and keep the original completely combined `dt`? I know the original data has 8 rows per unique `row_names`. And our result will have number of unique `tickers * 8 = 16` rows. But the things I would like to do after this might require having your `lapply` solution in one big `dt` again. I would like to avoid having to `rbindlist` them. Just a thought!

Comment: Modified the above to return the original with a list column having the means for each row. Note: the new function uses `dplyr::filter`

Comment: is there anyway to do it using `data.table` ? My data is quite large and I'm not sure `dplyr` is going to be as efficient